# IOS SFSafariView clear session

Tags: ios, authentication, cookies, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm encountering an issue with SFSafariVewController that when I logout and login without restarting the app, the login happens automatically by session/cookie data. If I restart the app after logout, this does not happen, meaning that it's session data, which is not persisted and is not shared with safari either.

I've tried to clear the URLCache and the HTTPCookieStorage shared cookies, but that does not work, they are pretty much empty. I have to use SFSafariView as per security conventions, so I can't switch to webview or anything.

Is there a way to completely clear a SFSafariView session/cache/cookies after the user dismisses it?